# update in mysql_query often works correctly.but sometime return no results

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [update in mysql_query sometime return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135120/update-in-mysql-query-sometime-return-null)

I use `update` in `mysql_query` in my PHP code. On localhost (in xampp) my code works correctly, but on the production host, the code often works correctly but sometime returns no result for update query.

If the update failed, it must return 'error' or '0' but it does not return any result. Why?

This is my code:

```
<?php
.
.
.
$QUERY_TRANSACTION = mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
if(!$QUERY_TRANSACTION){
    echo "error 101" ;
    exit;
}
$seed_query = "INSERT INTO seeds VALUES('','$username','$theTime','در انتظار')";
$seed_result = mysql_query($seed_query);
if(mysql_affected_rows()!=1){
    $QUERY_TROLLBACK = mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
    echo "error 102";       
    exit;       
}
$seed_id = mysql_insert_id();                           
$_SESSION['SEED_ID'] = $seed_id;

$query_values = "(NULL,'$list_number[0]',0,$seed_id)";                  
for($i=1;$i<count($list_number);$i++){
    $query_values .= ",(NULL,'$list_number[$i]',0,$seed_id)";
}               
$r_query = "INSERT INTO rc_members VALUES $query_values";
$r_result = mysql_query($r_query);
if(mysql_affected_rows()<=0){
    $QUERY_TROLLBACK = mysql_query('ROLLBACK'); 
    echo "error 103";       
    exit;       
}
$QUERY_COMMIT = mysql_query('COMMIT');
//--------------
$QUERY_TRANSACTION = mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');
if(!$QUERY_TRANSACTION){
    echo "error 104" ;
    exit;
}
$s_status = the_process($list_number,$m,$seed_id);                                          
if($s_status == 'successful_proc'){
    $s_query = "UPDATE seeds SET status='انجام شده' WHERE id=$seed_id";                                                     
    $s_result = mysql_query($s_query);
    //----------------logg file
    $filename = "debug.txt" ;
    $filepointer =fopen($filename ,"w") ;
    fwrite($filepointer , print_r($s_result,true)) ;
    fclose($filepointer) ;              
    //-----------------------
    if(!$s_result){
        echo "error 105".$s_result;                 
        exit;
    }
    $QUERY_COMMIT = mysql_query('COMMIT');
    echo 'successfuly process';
}else{
    $QUERY_TROLLBACK = mysql_query('ROLLBACK');
    echo 'error 106';
    exit;
}
$QUERY_COMMIT = mysql_query('COMMIT');  

?>
```

always "sucsessfully process" printed.but sometime "error 105" printed without any value for $s_result; 
i try to save the $s_result in file and see the no result save in file.
in other word the $s_result is null.
thank's

Comment: `echo '';` Typo? You're not echoing anything if `$s_status == 'successful_proc'` is false.

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).  You should also be checking (or logging) the result of [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/mysql_error) when things go wrong here.

Comment: Agreed with @Charles. The `mysql_xxx()` functions have been considered obsolete and insecure for years. If at all possible, please switch to one of the other APIs that PHP provides. (The `mysqli_xxx()` functions are very similar, and the conversion process is generally pretty painless)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that MySql returns false in case of no record effected or error

You can use mysql_affected_rows() after the query instead of

```
if(!$s_result){
        echo "error 105".$s_result;                 
        exit;
}
```

you can use

```
if(mysql_affected_rows($s_result) == -1){
        echo "error 105".$s_result;                 
        exit;
}
```

link for manual of the function : 
[mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)